# How to render from a html file using Angularjs ng-bind-html

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm using ng-bind-html to render a html code to my page, but my code is too long. So I put it in a HTML file. How can I do that?
This is my HTML and Js controller.My page include this:

```
<div ng-controller="modalPopup"><div ng-bind-html="renderHtml(message)"></div></div>
```

JS controller:

```
angular.module('mainApp', []).
controller('modalPopup', function($scope, $http,$sce) {
    $scope.renderHtml = function(value) {
     return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
  };
  $scope.message = '';
});
```

I want to put a big block of code HTML to `$scope.message` 
How can I do that. Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include content from the file into your HTML then you should use ngInclude:

```
<div ng-controller="modalPopup"><p ng-include="'path/to/file.html'"></p></div>
```

Comment: It's important to have the single quote in the include path. Thanks.